# My program that I created to check whether a number is prime or not is not giving out any output

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, scanf, primes

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i, n, prime=0;
    printf("Enter any positive integer:\n");
    scanf("%d", n);
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            prime=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(n==1){
        printf("1 is neither prime not composite.");
    }
    else{
        if(prime==0){
            printf("%d is a prime number.", n);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d is not a prime number.", n);
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what the problem here is but it never works.
It only takes in the input but then after that just shows a blank line and then nothing happens. I also compared it with another code for the same problem online and it looked almost looked similar and I couldn't find the problem here.

Comment: Didn't you get any warnings? Specifically about `scanf("%d", n);` ?

Comment: Another issue: `for(i=2; i<=n; i++){` `n` can always divide `n` , even if prime !!

Comment: you must call n by reference when taking input. try scanf("%d", &n)

Answer (score 2):

Enable all compiler warnings to save time.

`"%d"` in `scanf()` expects a matching `int *`, not an `int`.

```
// scanf("%d", n);
scanf("%d", &n);
```

Code iterates too far, should iterate less than `n`

```
// for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
for(i=2; i<n; i++){
// or even better and faster
for(i=2; i<=n/i; i++){
```

Test Inverted?

When `n%i==0` is true, it imples `n` is *not* a prime.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your program but instead of blank output, I got a Segmentation fault:

```
Enter any positive integer:
12
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

You need to pass address of variable rather than actual variable to scanf method, see [examples here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanf-and-fscanf-in-c-simple-yet-poweful/). So scanf statement which is like this:

```c
scanf("%d", n);
```

becomes this:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

I tested and your program started giving output as expected:

```
c-posts : $ ./a.out 
Enter any positive integer:
14
14 is not a prime number.
```

**Edit**:

From @Jabberwocky's comment I noticed that your prime number calculation logic seems doesn't seem to be working okay. You're currently iterating from [2..n] . Note that n%(i=n) would always be zero. You need to exclude `n` from loop range like this:

```c
for(i=2; i < n; i++){
   // ...
}
```

Or you can also iterate till `sqrt(n)` which would have less iterations:

```c
for(i=2; i< sqrt(n); i++){
      // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I agree it sounds confusing that even I don't know :-D . I usually comment like this so that I don't sound rude/agressive. Let me update this comment

Comment: _"You need to..."_ is neither rude nor agressive at all but it's clear. But there are more problems. Did you check e.g. with 17?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Thanks a lot for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

For starters the argument of the call of `scanf` is incorrect.

```
 scanf("%d", n);
```

You have to write

```
 scanf("%d", &n);
```

Also there is no great sense to use a signed integer number to check whether it is a prime number. Use an unsigned integer type as for example `unsigned int`.

And any prime number is divisible by itself. So due to the condition in the for loop

```
for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
```

the variable `prime` will be always set to `1` because when `i` is equal to `n`  then `n % i` is equal to `0`.

Change the for loop the following way

```
for( i = 2; prime == 0 && i <= n / i; i++ )
{
    if ( n % i == 0 ) prime = 1;
}
```

However if the number is an even number and is not equal to `2` then it is clear that it is not a prime number. You can check this before the for loop to skip it for even numbers.

Pay attention to that the user can enter `0`. In this case your program will output that `0` is a prime number though it is not a prime number.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    
    printf( "Enter any positive integer: " );
    scanf( "%u", &n);
    
    int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;
    
    for ( unsigned int i = 2; prime &&  i <= n / i; i++ )
    {
        if ( n % i == 0 ) prime = 0;
    }
    
    if ( n  < 2 )
    {
        printf( "%u is neither prime not composite.\n", n );
    }
    else if ( prime )
    {
        printf( "%u is a prime number.\n", n );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%u is not a prime number.\n", n );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make it:
scanf("%d", &n);